# JQuery messing with my form Quotes

Tags: jquery

I have a form that uses .delegate to apply input validation to the form however, it appears any form with quotes just disappears.. No errors, the quote just disappears.  Anyone know why this is happening? The only work around is to output the default value in the textbox as & #34; otherwise, the quotes will not appear in the textbox, even if it is actually in the value (view source).

The input type="text" also uses CSS3 styling, not sure if this has anything to do with it..

Basically, input type="text" value="quotes""" or value="quotes"" will only display 'quotes' in the rendered html, while the source has the correct value in it.

It's only doing this on textboxes being targeted by the .delegate code, which is applying "blur" "focus" on the text boxes, and the function is just adding classes and checking if val() = "".. the actual value in the textbox isn't being passed in the .delegate function.

The only time the textboxes which are in the delegate code:

```
    if ($(this).val()=="")
    if ($("#divid").val()=="")
```

Comment: Please give more details? What do you mean by the "quote just disappears"?

Comment: Need to see your .delegate() code please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to escape the quotes:

Either use `&quot;` (NOT to be used to mark attributes).
When your string is constructed using `"`, the attribute markers should be escaped using `\"`.

Examples:

- `"<input type=&quot;text&quot;>"` **wrong**, cannot use `&quot;` to mark attributes
- `"<input type="text">"` **wrong**, the inner quotes has to be escaped
- `"<input type=\"text\">`" **OK**, properly escaped.
- `"<input value=\"&quot;\">"` **OK**, properly escaped. Parsed to an input field with a value of a quotation mark (`"`).

### EDIT

To clarify: `<input type="text" value="quotes""">` within a single quote (`) *OR* HTML source are interpreted in this way:

1. Detected `<input` start tag.
2. Found an attribute called `type`.
3. The `type` attribute has a value (`=`)
4. The first non-whitespace character after the `=` character is a quote`"`. Searching for the first occurence of a quote after this quote..
5. End quote found, the value of `type` is `type`.
6. Found another attribute: `value`
7. The attribute defines a value, because a `=` is found.
8. The first non-whitespace character is a quote. Search for the next quote after this quote.
9. Quote mark found, the value of the `value` attribute is `quotes`.
10. Looking for the next attribute...
11. Found an unexpected `""`. Ignored.
12. Found close tag, the final parsed element is: `<input type="text" value="quotes">`.

When your JavaScript string is defined using double quotation marks,`"`, the previously used substring will cause a JavaScript error: `"<input type="`*text*. The JS interpreter found an unexpected character after the closing quote: `t`.

Comment: But i don't have to do this for boxes which do not have any .delegate targeted to it?  Because it views fine in the textbox on other fields without having to escape the quotes.

Comment: @JBNizet See the bottom of my answer for the explanation. `\"` should be used inside a string which is marked by `"`. `&quot;` should be used to add `"` in a HTML attribute.

Comment: Why do i not have to do this on other fields, is it because .delegate is being targeted to certain textboxes?

Comment: Why do i not have to do this on all the fields on my form, just on the ones using delegate.. and the code is correct as you suggested.

Comment: Show your code. I cannot improve my answer even more if you don't show what's going wrong. Based on the information you provided, my answer should work.

Comment: input type="text" value="quotes""" works in other form fields, only the ones with the delegate targeted to it doesn't...  The textbox value isn't being passed in the delegate function.

Comment: @ZeeTee Are you still struggling with this question?